# how to set each number in a string as its own string in a batch file

Tags: string, batch-file

So i was making a batch file recently, and i made a string. Later i needed to set each number as its own string (its hard to describe).

For example:

the input is:

```
set str=2043
```

so, i want to set 2, 0, 4 and 3 as their own string like this:

```
set str1=2
set str2=0
set str3=4
set str4=3
```

but lets say i dont know what `str` is. i just know that its 4 numbers.

I tried to browse the web but the i didnt find anything :P

Thanks for the help :D

Comment: No, I don't understand. Please, post a clear example, like "if input is `set string=2043` the output is..." Please, modify the question, do NOT post details or code in comments!

Comment: sorry, im kinda new to this website. but anyway i just edited it now, hope its more clear now :) tell me if its not

Comment: Not yet. Given `set str=2043` as input (and the other values in the example), what is the OUTPUT you want??? Or, are the `str1=2` etc. the output?

Comment: yeah thats the output! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the data you want is *array*:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set string=2043

rem Separate each digit in its "own string" (element) of "str" array
set i=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('cmd /U /C echo %string%^| find /V ""') do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "str!i!=%%a"
)

set str
```

Previous code separate the string "2043" in an array called "str" with 4 elements. For further details on array management in Batch files, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).